# WPF Datagrid Style not working for DataGrid with a DataTable as the ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and its `ItemSource` is set to the `DefaultView` of a `DataTable` as follows

```
TestGrid.ItemsSource = custTable.DefaultView;
```

It works fine, What i really want to do is that if the `DataGrid` contains a cell having the value "0" i want that cell to be coloured yellow no matter where ever the cell is located in the `DataGrid`. for that i did the following in the XAML part....

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="TestGrid" Height="auto" Width="auto" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

But this is not working.. How can i solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a local control resource like in the second example [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/using-styles/)

Comment: i don't think i can use that since my `DataGrid` data are dynamically generated.

Comment: You XAML is a little fishy... because it defines `<DataGrid.Columns>` but it doesn't set `AutoGeneratedColumns` to `false`... but other than that, make `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}">` and it should work... where `Col1` is whatever column name you're binding to.

Comment: i can't bind the columns because i don't know  anything about the column headers, they are generated dynamically by a data table and they can change.

Comment: i can't set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` because otherwise  there will be no data available in the DataGrid i.e., the columns are AutoGenarated.